# how to refresh fragment with navigation component?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

when I add this action which call the same fragment my app crash

```
 <action
            android:id="@+id/action_order_details_to_order_details"
            app:destination="@id/order_details"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_to_left"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_from_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_to_right" />
```

Comment: what kind of crash are you getting ? can you write it more detailed ?

Comment: thanks I solved it, it was because there is bundle return null .